# Accessing firebase database returns nil swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to access database through this code :

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            print(value)
          }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Here is my database :

[image]

The value printed is nil. I don't understand why...

What I tried :
I printed the value of the snapshot which is a dictionary.

Comment: Can you share the code where you get the reference to the database? (ref) Is there a reason you want to access data once? Take a look at the example from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

Comment: I think accessing it once is sufficient.

Comment: Quick question: Is `snapshot.value` nil? Or is `value` nil, because the cast as a Dictionary with `as? NSDictionary` failed?

Comment: if you do `snapshot.value as? [String]`, or snapshot.value `as? [[String: String]]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is casting the data as? NSDictionary

Can you try:
let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]